# How can find_package find third party dependency

Tags: cmake

I have read the documentation for [find_package](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html) and also read the documentation for [mastering it](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/book/mastering-cmake/chapter/Finding%20Packages.html). However, imo, both of these are simply inefficient for me. It says it will search in the following [locations](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html#config-mode-search-procedure), which for staters doesn't even define what `<prefix>/` is so I am already not off to a good start.

I have installed pybind11 stated from their documentation with [PyPi](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installing.html#include-with-pypi) and it is located in `...\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pybind11\share\cmake\pybind11\pybind11Config`. So I know that it exists... but how do I tell CMake to find it there?

On all the tutorials people just have `find_package(pybind11 REQUIRED)` and it simply finds it, however when I print `message(" A MESSAGE ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH}")` it's empty... so where DOES IT SEARCH!? If I install a third party dependency or install something it's typically in program files and not installed in the usual locations that are defined by the CMake locations search, so I am finding it bizarre how CMake can find anything...?

I am setting up a basic `CMakeLists.txt` and installed pybind11 with PyPi, but, of course my `find_package(pybind11 REQUIRED)` cannot find it and nobody can show me how to set this up properly so that CMake will find anything using find_package.

Comment: "It says it will search in the following locations, which for staters doesn't even define what `<prefix>/` is" - The values of the prefixes are described below, read from "The set of installation prefixes is constructed using the following steps.". As for "so where DOES IT SEARCH!?", then we don't know setup on your machine. You may run `cmake` with additional `--debug-find` option, so CMake will output more information about `find_package` settings and will even print locations of a config script which are actually checked.

Comment: I guess the easiest way would be to use PATHS Property. Something like find_package(pybind REQUIRED PATHS <some path to search for>).
Haven't tried it out, but I mostly use the find_package command that way.

Answer (score 0):

> So I know that it exists... but how do I tell CMake to find it there?

Package owners who want consumers to consume their package with CMake have the responsibility of providing their own CMake configuration.  The responsibility of this CMake configuration is to specify where their package artifacts can be found (libraries, source files, etc) and how to configure CMake to consume it (i.e., what are the targets, compiler settings, etc).

Ideally, this means package owners provide either the [CMake configuration or CMake modules](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html#search-modes) that handle this configuration.

> On all the tutorials people just have find_package(pybind11 REQUIRED) and it simply finds it,

Yes, this means that the package owners already provided their CMake configuration files, and made them available in standard locations in the file systems.

> however when I print message(" A MESSAGE ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH}") it's empty...

Yes, that is the expected outcome.  By default `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` is empty, and its responsibility is to allow users like you and me to provide custom paths where you installed external libraries.

Say you have a project which consumes a bunch of external libraries, and you decided to install them in `./external`.  To get CMake to pick up those dependencies, you pass something like the following:

```
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/external")
```

See the documentation on [`CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH.html)

> so where DOES IT SEARCH!?

The CMake documentation provides a thorough list of all the directory locations where `find_package` searches for the relevant CMake config files:

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html#search-procedure

For CMake Find modules, `find_packages` checks the directory locations listed in [`CMAKE_MODULE_PATH`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_MODULE_PATH.html#variable:CMAKE_MODULE_PATH) which, again, is empty by default.

> I am setting up a basic CMakeLists.txt and installed pybind11 with PyPi, but, of course my find_package(pybind11 REQUIRED) cannot find it and nobody can show me how to set this up properly so that CMake will find anything using find_package.

You need to troubleshoot your own call to `find_package(pybind11 REQUIRED)`.  If you're deploying pybind11 in non-standard dir paths then you have the responsibility of configuring your project to be able to find it.

Comment: I was following this tutorial, https://medium.com/practical-coding/setting-up-a-c-python-project-with-pybind11-and-cmake-8de391494fca

Can you help me understand where setup the configuration to find pybind11? Because on the pybind11 documentation it's generally installed via pip. He did not set the paths via GUI or cmake command line execution so I don't understand how he found it.